# PHP Unit 9 mock fails

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking

I have been trying to write a simple Unit Test on PHP version 8.0.1 and PHPUnit 9, with the same logic I been doing this on the older version (PHP: 7.4, PHPUnit 7):

MysqlService.php

```php
 public function doSomething()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

UserService.php

```php
public function doSomething()
    {
        return $this->mysqlService->doSomething();
    }
```

UserServiceTest.php

```php
/**
     * @test
     */
    public function doSomething_test()
    {
        $mock['mysqlService'] = $this->getMockBuilder(MysqlService::class)
            ->setMethods(['doSomething'])
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $mock['mysqlService']->expects($this->once())
            ->method('doSomething')
            ->willReturn('mockedValue');

        $userService = new UserService();
        $this->assertEquals('mockedValue', $userService->doSomething());
    }
```

In this example, I'm simply trying to mock the result of `MysqlService->doSomething()` to be `mockedValue`, but when I ran the command:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Unit/Service/UserServiceTest.php
```

I get

```
root@30fdcf7735ea:/var/www/html# ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Unit/Service/UserServiceTest.php 
PHPUnit 9.5.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.465, Memory: 6.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) UserServiceTest::doSomething_test
Failed asserting that null matches expected 'mockedValue'.

/var/www/html/tests/Unit/Service/UserServiceTest.php:247

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

I might be doing something wrong that changed in the new version but googling didn't help.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually passing your mock to your service somewhere?

Comment: UserService class loads MysqlService in the constructor and it doesn't pass anything. I'm not sure how to pass the mocks to the service

Comment: This definitely doesn't sound like it has anything to do with the version of PHP or PHPUnit. If you don't pass your mock to your service, your test isn't going to use it, it'll just use the regular MysqlService that you create in the constructor. I'd recommend reading a bit about dependency injection - you should be passing in ("injecting") your dependencies, not loading them in the services that use them.

Comment: Tnx @iainn it makes sense now, I guess the issue is I'm trying to avoid dependency injection in my project, which causing this to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get it off the unanswered list:

`$mock['mysqlService']` is not passed to your `UserService` at all, so the user service does not use the mocked SQL service.